# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/cache/CacheLoader

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, pom.xml

When i am trying to execute my kafka spark project.
I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/cache/CacheLoader
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:55)
```

I tried below methods which are already asked in the forum:
1) Added

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.iot.app.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>iot-kafka-producer</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<name>IoT Kafka Producer</name>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId> 
        <version>2.1.0</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spark-project.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>unused</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

## Code:Spark Consumer code

```
package datapipeline;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;


public class CustomerKafkaConsumerThread {
    String broker;
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

    public void  sparkKafkaConsumer(String topics,String broker){
        this.broker=broker;
        SparkConf conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("CustomerKafkaConsumerThread").setMaster("local");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc=new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(2000));

        Map<String, String> kafkaParams=new HashMap<String, String>();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list",broker);
        Set<String> topicSet=Collections.singleton(topics);

         // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages=KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        jssc, 
        String.class,
        String.class, 
        StringDecoder.class, 
        StringDecoder.class, 
        kafkaParams, 
        topicSet);

        JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(Tuple2::_2);
        System.out.println("........." + lines);
        JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)));
        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
            .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);
        wordCounts.print();

        // Start the computation
        jssc.start();
        jssc.awaitTermination();


    }
}
```

2) Removed google.guava jarfile from the build path in eclipse and added again as external jar.

But below two methods have not helped in my case.

Kindly someone help me in resolving this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you, please, add complete pom.xml to the question?

Comment: How did you run the codes? Using spark-submit or not?

Comment: Hi @zsxwing Thanks for the response. No i have not executed the program with spark-submit. I am executing my program in eclipse 
run->java application. 
Spark consumer code is uploaded for your reference.

Comment: @semsorock thanks for replay sure.. upload my complete pom.xml and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use same `scala` version in your dependencies. Please, try change `spark-streaming-kafka_2.10` to `spark-streaming-kafka_2.11`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And use same `spark` version. For example `1.6.3`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-network-common_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have made changes in the pom file and changed the version of related versions dependencies also. But still the issue is seen :(

Comment: the main reason is `guava` version. `spark-core` use `guava` version `14.0.1` (as provided). can you downgrade your `guava` version?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked after changing to 2.11 version