# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/cache/CacheLoader for maven project

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I did upgrade spark version from 2.2.2 to 2.3.2 in maven project but getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spark_project/guava/cache/CacheLoader
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:57)
```

The pom.xml file contains the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Which dependency should I add to get rid of this problem for spark 2.3.2?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377333/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-spark-project-gua

Comment: That is for the different version of spark.